# Sony Ip camera opencv Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to take images from an IP cam (sony snc p1) for motion detection using opencv java. The stream is in mjpeg format and I am using opencv's VideoCapture to try to retrieve an image. I can grab an image from a video file using videocapture but when I try to open the camera doesn't work. I can  view the stream on vlc but  that ip address doesn't work on opencv.  This is the code that I use:

```
while (true){
  VideoCapture camera1=newVideoCapture("http://192.168.0.101/mjpeg");                    
  if (!camera1.isOpened())                  
   System.out.println("Cannot open file");
}
```

Comment: You should't instantiate a new VideoCapture instance in a while loop over and over again: do it once before the while loop. What OS are you using ? It's good you tested with VLC. What video support do you have OpenCV built with ? Try opening the IP camera directly first. For example, if you have OpenCV built with FFMPEG support, open the camera straight from FFMPEG alone first (similarly for GStreamer, V4L, etc.). If doesn't work there, it's not OpenCV related. If it does, double check OpenCV has been built with the same video support. HTH

Comment: Worst case scenario, from a pragmatic perspective see if there's another IP Camera Java library, and if so it will probably allow you access the stream as a `BufferedImage` which could plug into a `Mat`

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? In openCV 2.4 this is a known bug. (fixed in later versions)

You can olso try adding a dummy param, at the end, something like `camera1.open("http://192.168.0.101/?dummy=video.mjpg");` 
because opencv VideoCapture expects an extension at the end of the file name.